# Please can someone evaluate my code and tell me where im going wrong?

Tags: html, web

I am new to web, and this is my first project...

I feel as though i am doing something wrong layout wise,

am i possibly using too much divs?

my css is separate and i feel pretty confident with css however i want to now make this webpage responsive, what would be the easiest method for my self? i am guessing media queries?

i always have issues with layouts and positioning of things

thank you for your help, really appreciated

```html
<div class="bottom">

    <div class="licensetxt">

        <h2>License</h2>
        <a name="Link"></a>
        <br>

        <input type="button" id="btnx" style="background-image:url('arrowup.png')" />
        <!-- <img style="position:absolute; left:1100px; top:815px; width:40px; padding: 1px; margin: 1px" src="arrowup.png"> -->


        <h4>License Agreement</h4>

        <p>By purchasing these (“sounds”) you are granted a license to use these sounds for specific uses under the conditions set out below. Ownership remains with the creator Wingman Inc Ltd, and you are required to abide by the following licensing terms.</p>

        <h4>Rights</h4>

        <p>
            This license grants the purchaser an ongoing, non-exclusive, worldwide license.
            You are licensed to use the sounds to create products for yourself or for your clients.
            You may modify the sounds according to your requirements and use them royalty free in your personal and commercial projects. For example, you may use these sounds in an application, website or mobile app you will be designing for a client.
        </p>

        <p>Wingman Inc Ltd will not be responsible for any outcome that may occur during the course of usage of these resources.</p>

        <h4>Prohibitions</h4>

        <p>
            This license prohibits the redistribution, resell, lease, license, sub-license or offer of the file downloaded to any third party.
            For any resalable web applications or mobile software programs, you should not include these sounds as an additional attachment meant for purchase, such as In App Purchasing. This will be considered as a redistribution of our resources which is forbidden by us and pursuant under European Law.
        </p>


    </div>


    <div class="sound">
        <img style="position:absolute; left:620px; top:1400px; width:50px; padding: 1px; margin: 1px;" src="sound-icon-grey@2x.png">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML looks fine, although personally I would use something like padding with CSS to organise your layout rather than `<br>`. What exactly do you want to make "responsive", and what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

## responsive

Making a website responsive with media queries can take a lot of time. Often too much time.

1. I would recommend learning a framework like [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
2. Media queries are still a must. You'll need to scale fonts and other things.
3. Also take a look at REM for fonts, em for padding etc.. They can also help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

**1: Am I doing something wrong?**

Well, learning web-development is a process and your code will not be perfect from the starting, but by practicing it will get better.

You could take a look at HTML5 syntax. Here you'll use article / main / section and some other tags instead of div, which will help for readability.

**2: How to make it responsive?**

You could base the width of things on the width of parent divs (display: block; in css, this will make a child div 100% of the width of the parent div). Read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

You could also use media queries. These are meant to make more significant design changes based on screen-size. You can find more on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).